# Apache Beam: IllegalStateException - Value only available at runtime after upgrading to beam 2.41.0

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I upgraded my Apache Beam version from 2.34.0 to 2.41.0 and getting the following error when trying to build the template.

**The error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value only available at runtime, but accessed from a non-runtime context: RuntimeValueProvider{propertyName=spannerInstanceId, default=defaultinstanceid}
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$RuntimeValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:254)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerConfig.withInstanceId(SpannerConfig.java:165)
        at .... my code constructing SpannerConfig ...
```

**My code looks like this:**

```java
  private static SpannerConfig getValidatedSpannerConfig(MyCustomOptions options) {
    SpannerConfig spannerConfig =
        SpannerConfig.create()
            .withProjectId(options.getSpannerProjectId())
            .withInstanceId(options.getSpannerInstanceId())
            .withDatabaseId(options.getSpannerDatabaseId());
    spannerConfig.validate();
    return spannerConfig;
  }
```

**Using Beam version <= `2.39.0` solving that issue.**

---

Seems like the SpannerConfig `withInstanceId` method is causing this runtime read by calling `get()` ahead of time.
Is there a chance there is a bug in 2.40.0 and 2.41.0 versions of `org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform` ?

Decompiled version of 2.41.0 is:

```java
  public SpannerConfig withInstanceId(ValueProvider<String> instanceId) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(instanceId);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(instanceId.get()); // <<<<<< The problematic line
    return toBuilder().setInstanceId(instanceId).build();
  }
```

Decompiled version of 2.39.0 is:

```java
  public SpannerConfig withInstanceId(ValueProvider<String> instanceId) {
    return toBuilder().setInstanceId(instanceId).build();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a [bug](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/22146) there, introduced in 2.40.0, where it tries to read a value when it's not yet accessible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Alexey. I am proposing a PR https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/23294